# OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: best_model_101class.hdf5{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to load an ai model from tensorflow
I use this line to import load_model:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import load_model
```

And I use try to access the model here using load_model

```
tensorflow.keras.backend.clear_session() 
model_best = load_model('best_model_101class.hdf5', compile=False) #error here 
print('model successfully loaded!')
```

This is the error message I get when the program tries to run these lines

```
OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: best_model_101class.hdf5{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
```

Can anyone help me fix this error? I've searched online and tried those solutions, but to no avail.

I've tried running it on a virtual Linux Ubuntu machine, which didn't work. Currently, I use a Windows 10 computer, with a virtual Linux Ubuntu machine (microsoft wsl)